# Auxiliary tree data in h2o's MOJOs for random forest

Tags: python, r, random-forest, h2o

It seems like h2o's MOJO zip files for its random forest algorithm contain "auxiliary" tree data that account for roughly 75% of the total MOJO file size.

1. What is this auxiliary tree data exactly used for?
2. Is it necessary to have this data for deployed models that only perform forecasting?
3. If not, is it possible to omit storing the auxiliary data when calling `h2o.download_mojo`?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Statistics.

For example, the weighted number of rows for each of the child nodes.

You can look at the AuxInfo data structure here:

- https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-genmodel/src/main/java/hex/genmodel/algos/tree/SharedTreeMojoModel.java

The MOJO printing tool has a special flag (--detail) that prints out this information.

See the tool used here:

- http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-genmodel/javadoc/overview-summary.html#viewing-a-mojo

2. Strictly speaking, no.  The prediction calculation does not require the "aux" information.

However the I'm going to guess the current Java genmodel reader code (3.16.0.4) might not parse properly if that information isn't there.

(You can try yourself by unzipping the mojo, removing that aux file, and rezipping it again.)

3. No, as of the current version (3.16.0.4) this feature does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Tom.